# HTML button to NOT submit form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form. Outside that form, I have a button. A simple button, like this:

```
<button>My Button</button>
```

Nevertheless, when I click it, it submits the form. Here's the code:

```
<form id="myform">
    <label>Label 
      <input />
    </label>
</form>
<button>My Button</button>
```

All this button should do is some JavaScript. But even when it looks just like in the code above, it submits the form. When I change the tag button to span, it works perfectly. But unfortunately, it needs to be a button. Is there any way to block that button from submitting the form? Like e. g.

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myform').doNotSubmit();">My Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1155, accepted):

I think this is the most annoying little peculiarity of HTML... That button needs to be of type "button" in order to not submit.

```
<button type="button">My Button</button>
```

**Update 5-Feb-2019:** As per the [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type) (and also [HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#attr-button-type)):

> The *missing value default* and *invalid value default* are the Submit
>   Button state.

Comment: @Powerslave any reason to not `to use <button>`

Comment: @SandipPingle There's no reason to use it, unless you need some really complex kind of styling. Also, IE6 and IE7 (fortunately being phased out) handle  `<button>`s incorrectly in some cases. Additionally, `<button>` is not 100% cross-browser-compatible in that different browsers may submit different values for the same `<button>` when used in a form.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it's not a *peculiarity*. The default value of the `type` attribute in a `<button>` tag is `submit`. When changed to `type=button`, the `<button>` is given no default behavior. See `type` attribute here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 43):

`return false;` at the end of the onclick handler will do the job. However, it's be better to simply add `type="button"` to the `<button>` - that way it behaves properly even without any JavaScript.

Comment: Buttons which do not submit forms are only useful with JavaScript enabled anyway... I agree that type="button" is cleaner though.

Comment: `return false;` does not work in all scenarios, while `type="Button"` does. Even with enabled JavaScript.

Answer (score 34):

By default, html buttons submit a form.

> This is due to the fact that even buttons located outside of a form act as submitters (see the W3Schools website: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp)

In other words, the button type is "submit" by default

```
<button type="submit">Button Text</button>
```

> Therefore an  easy way to get around this is to use the *button type*.

```
<button type="button">Button Text</button>
```

> Other options include returning false at the end of the *onclick* or any other handler for when the button is clicked, or to using an < input> tag instead

To find out more, check out the Mozilla Developer Network's information on buttons: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 17):

Dave Markle is correct. From [W3School's website](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp):

> Always specify the type attribute for
>   the button. The default type for
>   Internet Explorer is "button", while
>   in other browsers (and in the W3C
>   specification) it is "submit".

In other words, the browser you're using is following W3C's specification.

Answer (score 7):

Another option that worked for me was to add onsubmit="return false;" to the form tag.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Semantically probably not as good a solution as the above methods of changing the button type, but seems to be an option if you just want a form element that won't submit.

Answer (score 3):

It's recommended not to use the `<Button>` tag. Use the `<Input type='Button' onclick='return false;'>` tag instead. (Using the "return false" should indeed not send the form.)

Some [reference material](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_BUTTON.html)

Comment: It's enough to use `<input type="button" />`, and it's enough to `return false;` - there's no need to do both.

Comment: I don't agree that it is recommended not to use the button tag. If you don't use it, you lose some accessibility features that you would automatically get with the button tag. I'd say the button tag is actually recommended for elements that act as buttons.

Comment: according to the note in reference material you've linked: "While <input> elements of type button are still perfectly valid HTML, the newer <button> element is now the favored way to create buttons." So it's exactly the opposite you stated.

Comment: I'm in agreement with this answer, but I can also see the upsides of using a button tag with the correct type attribute.

Answer (score 1):

For accessibility reason, I could not pull it off with multiple `type=submit` buttons. The only way to work natively with a `form` with multiple buttons but *ONLY* one can submit the form when hitting the `Enter` key is to ensure that only one of them is of `type=submit` while others are in other type such as `type=button`. By this way, you can benefit from the better user experience in dealing with a form on a browser in terms of keyboard support.

Answer (score 1):

Late in the game, but you don't need ANY JavaScript code to use a button as a button.  The default behavior is to submit the form, most people don't realize that.  The type parameter has three options: submit (default), button and reset.  The cool thing about this is if you add an event handler it will bypass submitting the form.

```
<button type="button">My Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also way to prevent doing the submit when clicking the button.
To achieve this, you have to use `event.preventDefault()` method.

```js
document.querySelector("button#myButton").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  document.getElementById("output-box").innerHTML += "Sorry! <code>preventDefault()</code> won't let you submit this!<br>";
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myform">
        <label>Label 
          <input />
        </label>
      <button id="myButton">My Button</button>
    </form>

    <div id="output-box"></div>
    <script src="src/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```