# Onclick shouldn't trigger form data submission

Tags: javascript, html

I just found out that every time `onclick` event for my `<button>` placed inside `<form>` tag triggers, form submits it's data as if i clicked `<input type='submit'>`.
I don't want that. Buttons inside my form serve other task, form shouldn't submit data after i clicked one of them.

To be more clear, i want this code:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="POST">
    <button onclick="alert('hi!')">Button</button>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

to show alert "hi!" when i click on the Button and it shouldn't open Google after that. It should only show Google when i press "submit".

Comment: Esailija, it depends on a browser i think because i tested in in Chrome before i posted it in here and it redirects me to Google all right.

Comment: Yes I just realized that, different browsers can assume different `type` because you didn't specify it

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML button to NOT submit form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specify [`type="button"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/button#attr-type):

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('hi!')">Button</button>
```

From the linked article:

> This [submit] is the default if the attribute is not specified

Comment: Both answers worked, thanks a lot. I think this one is the best because it helps understanding why i had that problem in the first place.

Comment: @Alehar this should work (the button not submitting form) even if javascript is disabled, since `return false` is dependent on javascript being enabled

Comment: yeah sorry didn't see this question. hence +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
onclick="alert('hi!'); return false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery use a span rather than an input, put use the .button call and then set a click event.