# HTML Flickering when using JS function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change text in html using the DOM. I have a form with 2 radio buttons and a submit button. When submitted, it runs a JS function that should change text in HTML to reflect what answer they chose. However, whenever you click the submit button, it changes the text and then instantly flickers back to what the html shows. Why is it doing this? I've never seen this before. Here is the code...

```js
function answerNext()
{
 if(document.getElementById("question1").checked == true)
 {
  document.getElementById("qtext").innerText="You chose the first option";
 }else if (document.getElementById("question2").checked == true)
 {
  documet.getElementById("qtext").innerText="You chose the second option";
 }else
 {
  document.getElementById("qtext").innerText="You chose neither option";
  document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML="<h1>You clicked next</h1>";
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Dog Personailty Quiz</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Is now a good time to get a dog?</h1>
  <h2 id="qtext">Do you like to run a lot</h2>
  <div id="testdiv"></div>
  <form>
   <input type="radio" id="question1" value="option1"> Option 1
   <input type="radio" id="question2" value="option1"> Option 2
   <input type="submit" value="Next" onclick="answerNext();">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ideally, code posted in a snippet actually behaves as described. Can you make that happen?

Comment: Your js is changing the text, then the form submits which reloads the page which resets the text back to normal. There are many ways to prevent a form from submitting which I am sure you can find on google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Onclick shouldn't trigger form data submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223591/onclick-shouldnt-trigger-form-data-submission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you could change the input's attribute `type` to `"button"` but if you wish to keep it as a `submit` button you'll need to stop the forms submit event to prevent the page navigating away/refreshing.

You do this by using the first argument of the event's function. The first argument holds the event that was triggered. If the browser doesn't support this, there is a fallback using `window.event` (we are checking this first because some browsers only support the `argument` and some only the `window.event`).

Stop browser from triggering the submit event using this example:

```
function answerNext(evt)
{
    if (evt == null)
    {
        evt = window.event;
    }

    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    . . .
```

Secondly, you'll want to group the ratio inputs so only one can be selected at a time. Do this by creating a `fieldset` element and adding the name attribute to the inputs, connecting them to that group:

```
<fieldset id="group1">
    <input type="radio" id="question1" value="option1" name="group1"> Option 1
    <input type="radio" id="question2" value="option2" name="group1"> Option 2
</fieldset>
```

Also, there was an error in the `if else` statement where there's a typo `documet` should be `document`.

**Try out this code I've fixed for you:**

```js
function answerNext(evt)
{
 if (evt == null)
 {
  evt = window.event;
 }
  
  evt.preventDefault();
 evt.stopPropagation();
  
  if(document.getElementById("question1").checked == true)
 {
  document.getElementById("qtext").innerText="You chose the first option";
 }else if (document.getElementById("question2").checked == true)
 {
  document.getElementById("qtext").innerText="You chose the second option";
 }else
 {
  document.getElementById("qtext").innerText="You chose neither option";
  document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML="<h1>You clicked next</h1>";
 }
}
```

```css
fieldset#group1
{
  border: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Dog Personailty Quiz</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Is now a good time to get a dog?</h1>
  <h2 id="qtext">Do you like to run a lot</h2>
  <div id="testdiv"></div>
  <form>
      <fieldset id="group1">
        <input type="radio" id="question1" value="option1" name="group1"> Option 1
        <input type="radio" id="question2" value="option2" name="group1"> Option 2
      </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" value="Next" onclick="answerNext();">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your button type from `submit` to just `button` so the form doesn't actually submit.

```
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="answerNext();">
```

You'll also want to fix the typo (`documet`) and implement a radio group to prevent both from being selected. Finally, wrap your radio buttons and their text in `label` elements for accessibility and better usability (the label text becomes clickable).

**[Demo of all that](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wouch3ve/)**

```js
function answerNext() {
  if (document.getElementById("question1").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("qtext").innerText = "You chose the first option";
  } else if (document.getElementById("question2").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("qtext").innerText = "You chose the second option";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("qtext").innerText = "You chose neither option";
    document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = "<h1>You clicked next</h1>";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Is now a good time to get a dog?</h1>
<h2 id="qtext">Do you like to run a lot</h2>
<div id="testdiv"></div>
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" id="question1" value="option1" name="blah"> Option 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" id="question2" value="option1" name="blah"> Option 2</label>
  <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="answerNext(event);">
</form>
```