# Submitting a form, restrict to submit button only

Tags: jquery

I catch my forms submit with:

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(e){
 //do stuff
```

Here's my html

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="columns">
            <button type="submit" class="small right">Save</button>
       </div>
</div>
```

Also in my form are other buttons for deleting images:

```
<button class="tiny btn-caption" data-reveal-id="caption-modal">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

The problem is, these image buttons submit the form, how can I stop this?

Comment: Specify a `type`, otherwise behaviour depends on implementation. Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option1:**

Check

[HTML button to NOT submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form)

[Difference between <input type='button' /> and <input type='submit' />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit)

**Option 2:** Work around

You need to do `preventDefault()` for other buttons

Assuming  you are deleting using ajax call like below

```
$('.tiny btn-caption').click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault(); // it will cancel the default form submission behavior

  $.post({
   //Ajax stuff for deleting goes here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Buttons like `<button>Click to do something</button>` are submit buttons.

add `type="button"` it will restrict form submission

```
<button type="button" class="tiny btn-caption" data-reveal-id="caption-modal">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `<button>` will act as a submit button.

Try,

```
$("#my-form button[type!='submit']").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `remove` class for button which deletes images and prevent its action:

```
<button class="remove tiny btn-caption" data-reveal-id="caption-modal">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#my-form .remove').click(function(){
  // post another form or call ajax method
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply event handlers to the buttons themselves not the whole form

```
$('#my_form button').click(function(){
//or 
$('.tiny btn-caption, .small').click(function(){

 $.post(url,dataString,function(response){
    //handle resposne
  });

 return false;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the html input submit

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't answer the question posted. They wanted to stop buttons from submitting it too.