# React ES5: one button invoked two functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two react classes both have render function that returns forms with  a button. In class A, I had to import class B so i can use form from class B.

**My problem**: When I clicked the inner button, the outer button gets triggered as well but I only want the inner submit button to work.

**My attempt**: I checked the console and found out that it is giving me a warning: **validateDOMNesting: form cannot appear as a descendant of form.**

I did the research and thought that the problem may due to the nested form . So I found out a workaround from SO by changing the `<form></form>` in the class B to `<div></div>`, so it is no longer a form. Now it does not give me error on console, but the problem still remains: if I click the inner button, the outer button got triggered as well which invoked two functions in total.

**Where I need help:** I really want to figure out what cause this behavior(I am thinking maybe changing the tag does not change the nested form problem or maybe the way how I referencing the other class is not completely right)

**My code:**(Please notice that I simplified it)

```
var classA = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form
          className={this.props.className}
          id={this.props.controllerSingular + '_form'}
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          ref="some_form"
        >
          <FieldSet>
            <ClassB id={this.state.id} />
          </FieldSet>
          <button onClick={this.submit} className="btn btn-primary">
            Save
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  },
})

var classB = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button id="some_ID" className="some_name" onClick={this.handleRegAdd}>
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  },
  handleRegAdd: function() {
    var that = this
    var regLines = this.state.regulation
    regLines.push({
      reg_id: null,
      Type: $('.reg-type-select span.Select-value-label').text(),
      id: that.props.id,
      Hours: null,
      Minutes: null,
      Days: '',
      Start: null,
      End: null,
    })

    this.setState({
      regulations: regLines,
    })
  },
})
```

when I clicked the button from class B, which should only trigger function "handleRegAdd". However, it also triggered submit function in class A

Comment: Unfortunately, the simplification has left out things that are critical to understanding the problem. Where is `handleRegAdd` defined? FYI, you don't need to wrap the button in a div if nothing else is inside that div.

Comment: But also, the answer is probably just that you are using a `button` and the default type for a button is `submit`. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form

Comment: @Sia I have updated my handleRegAdd. It basically set the state, that's all. If the logic of code above looks correct, that means the error is from something else. I will look into that. Maybe it is not caused by something I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not related to the `validateDOMNesting` warning.

Button clicks (and other DOM events) bubble up the component tree.  That means that clicking on the button will trigger the `onClick` event for *all parent components* as well.

You can stop the bubbling by calling `event.preventDefault()` in your event handler.  It might look like this:

```
handleRegAdd: function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  // continue with the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Is there anything else that will cause the similar problem? Is there a name for this specific structure in react? Now I am really curious about the "bubble up the component tree" stuff since I feel like I missing a react knowledge and I wanna read more about it, but I cant seem to find the reading about it.

Comment: This (event bubbling) isn't specific to React. You can read about it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/1424833

Answer (score 0):

The default `type` for a button is `submit`, so to have the button not perform the form's `onSubmit` action, simply change the type to `button`:

```
<button type="button" id="some_ID" className="some_name" onClick={this.handleRegAdd}>
  Add
</button>
```

I mentioned this in my comment, and it's also covered here in this SO question: [HTML button to NOT submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form)