# How to handle multiple button in form?

Tags: javascript, html

In the below form when we click on save we are getting only form submit request to server.

```
    <form id="form1" action="service1" method="POST">
     <button id="id1" onclick="getcount('emp')" >clickhere</button>

     <input id="save"  type="submit" class="btn-small btn-primary" value="Save" name="Save"/>

     </form>
```

But when we click on clickhere button, we are getting two requests to server.
i.e. 1. post call service1
     2. service call in getCount() function.

But I need only getCount() function service call.

How can we handle the above scenario?

Comment: add `type="button"` to the clickhere button.

Comment: Look here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form

Answer (score 3):

Add type="button" to the button that makes the getcount() call so that it overrides the default "submit" behaviour.

`<button id="id1" type="button" onclick="getcount('emp')" >clickhere</button>`

Comment: thanks!! its working!!