# when I press enter while filling form, bs modal opens. How to prevent it?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

**I am using form in angular.**
When I click enter in any input field. It opens bsmodal.

Comment: Please post some code here. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello ! Some code would be nice, we can't help you like that…

Comment: Well its a large file. StackOverflow will not allow to post it here.

Comment: Maybe you have a button somewhere in the form which reacts to the 'enter' press and opens a modal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML button to NOT submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the enter keydown directly in the form like this:

```
<form (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to fix this with a `type="button"` on your button that opens your modal if it's inside a form element.

For reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825867/2413712
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type

Answer (score 0):

you are using html form or some angular component to create form?
You just have to stop the event
You can use following code if you can use jq in your application

```
$('form input').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I do this in typescript?

Comment: import jquery and then you can use the exact code.

import * as $ from 'jquery';