# What triggers the onsubmit event? How to configure that?

Tags: javascript

Naively you might assume that the event is triggered that when the (a?) input button of type "submit" is clicked.

In fact, as far as I'm able to ascertain, every button within a form triggers the event.

Is there some way to set a button to not trigger the event?

Comment: The simpliest way is to use a button `<button type="button">Click me, I won't submit the form</button>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML button to NOT submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> every button within a form triggers the event

No. Only submit buttons do. (As well as a few other cases such as when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed in a text input).

Note that `<button>` elements are `type="submit"` by *[default](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type)* and should be `type="button"` if you want a non-submit button for handing JS from.

You can also attach a JavaScript `click` event listener to a button and call [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the event object.

Answer (score 1):

Button's default type is submit. If you want buttons that don't submit, you have to change their type to button.