# How do i distinguish between a normal button and the submit button when using react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, modal-dialog, react-hook-form

Okay so i am creating a sign up Modal for a website. It is a 3-page form so i separated it into 3 different form components. So the aim is that on the first form page, I conditionally render a next button and a "Have an account? Login" button. when i click the next button, it moves to form 2 and the "Have an account? Login" button changes to a back button. and then when i click the next button again, i go to form 3 and the next button changes to a submit button, which would be used to submit the form. I took inspiration from the twitch sign up form. The problem is that all the buttons are included in the form tag and as such, they all act as a submit button, even when i only want the submit button on page 3 to act as a submit button. I would add the required code below.

The yup schema:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required(),
    email: yup.string().email().required(),
    password: yup.string().min(8).max(20).required(),
  });

const {register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }} = useForm({resolver: yupResolver(schema)});

const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data)
```

the form conditional:

```
const [form, setForm] = useState(1)

let view = null

    if(props.form === 1){
        view = <SignupForm1 
                    register={props.register} />
    }else if(props.form === 2){
        view = <SignupForm2 
                    register={props.register}/>
    }else{
        view = <SignupForm3 
                    register={props.register}/>
    }
```

The actual form:

```
                 <div  className='w-full h-96 flex flex-col pt-5 gap-5 px-5'>
                    <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit(props.onSubmit)} >
                        {view}

                        {props.form > 2 ? 
                        <button type='submit' className='w-full mt-5 h-10 rounded-md bg-learnode-green1 bg-opacity-10 font-semibold'>Submit</button> : 
                        <button  className='w-full mt-5 h-10 rounded-md bg-learnode-green1 bg-opacity-10 font-semibold disabled:bg-gray-300 disabled:bg-opacity-9 disabled:text-gray-500' onClick={() => props.setForm(box => box +1)}>Next Step</button>
                        }

                        {props.form > 1 ? 
                        <button className='w-full h-10 rounded-md bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-5 text-xs text-green-400 ' onClick={() => handleBack()} >Back</button> : 
                        <button className='w-full h-10 rounded-md bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-5 text-xs text-green-400 ' onClick={() => handleClick2()} >Already have an account? Login</button>
                        }
                    </form>
                </div>
```

As you can see, i created a form state and initiated it to Form 1. whenever the user clicks on the next step button, It moves to the next page, until it gets to Form 3 then the button turns to the submit button. The submit button is the only button with a type = 'submit' but if i click any other button, it still submits. Is there a way to make the form know that its only the submit button i want to submit the form or i have to rearrange my form in another way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML button to NOT submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form)

Comment: Explicitly set `<button type="button">` so that it does not submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, all the buttons are included in the same form tag, so they all act as `submit` buttons.

To fix this, split the buttons and the forms into separate components, and pass data between them using state or props.